# Does updating a view affects the base table?

Tags: oracle, view

When I updated a view which was created using a base table, the updation affected the base table as well. How is that possible? If view is considered as just a 'window' through which we can see a set of data of the base table then how can the base table change when I try to change the data inside a view.

Answer (score 1):

In some databases it's possible to update the source table(s) for a view if there is a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table, that is, you cant have derived columns, aggregate functions or a distinct clause in your view for example.

In Oracle, even if a view is not inherently updatable, updates may be allowed if an [INSTEAD OF DML trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS20041) is defined.

If you use mysql, you can read a detailed description about this feature [Updatable and insertable views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/view-updatability.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes to the state of underlying table using the view as long as the you are targeting the change in single table.

View is a security layer on top of table object and allows most of the DML operation as long as you do not violet the base rule.

Example:

CREATE TABLE T1
   (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), [Value] NVARCHAR(50))

CREATE TABLE T2
   (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), [Value] NVARCHAR(50))

--Dummy Insert
   INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('TestT1')

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('TestT2')

--Create View
   CREATE VIEW V1
   AS
   SELECT T1.ID AS T1ID, T2.ID AS T2ID, T1.Value AS T1Value, T2.Value AS T2Value FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
   ON T2.ID = T1.ID

--Check the result
   SELECT * FROM V1

--Insert is possible via view as long as it affects only one table

INSERT INTO V1 (T1Value) VALUES 
   ('TestT1_T1')

INSERT INTO V1 (T2Value) VALUES 
   ('TestT2_T2')

--Change is possible only if target is only one table
   UPDATE V1
   SET T1Value = 'Changed'--**
   WHERE T2ID = 1

--This is not allowed
   INSERT INTO V1 (T1Value, T2Value) VALUES 
   ('TestT1_T1','TestT2_T2')

--Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    --View or function 'V1' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

--Check T1 and T2 with each statement to see how it gets affected

--

Answer (score 0):

" If view is considered as just a 'window' through which we can see a set of data of the base table "
 - Where did you get this definition?

What oracle says about views:

> A view is a logical representation of another table or combination of
>   tables. A view derives its data from the tables on which it is based.
>   These tables are called base tables. Base tables might in turn be
>   actual tables or might be views themselves. All operations performed
>   on a view actually affect the base table of the view. You can use
>   views in almost the same way as tables. You can query, update, insert
>   into, and delete from views, just as you can standard tables.

Such a view into which you can update or insert are fondly named as "Updatable and Insertable Views". Oracle documentation about them is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/view-updatability.html).

Also, this is how the purpose of an "insert" statement is defined by Oracle:

> Use the INSERT statement to add rows to a table, the base table of a
>   view, a partition of a partitioned table or a subpartition of a
>   composite-partitioned table, or an object table or the base table of
>   an object view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can achieve the DML Operation in Views like  belows:

```
Create or replace view emp_dept_join as   Select d.department_id,  
d.department_name, e.first_name, e.last_name from employees
e, departments d where  e.department_id = d.department_id;   

SQL>CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_emp_dept
      INSTEAD OF INSERT ON emp_dept_join DECLARE v_department_id     departments.department_id%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
    BEGIN
    SELECT department_id INTO v_department_id
    FROM   departments
    WHERE  department_id = :new.department_id;
 EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO departments (department_id, department_name)
             VALUES (dept_sequence.nextval, :new.department_name)
             RETURNING ID INTO v_department_id; 
    END;
  INSERT INTO employees (employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_id)
         VALUES(emp_sequence.nextval, :new.first_name, :new.last_name, v_department_id); 
END insert_emp_dept;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

if the viwe is defined through a simple query involving single base relation and either containing primary key or candidate key, so there will be change in base relation if changing the view. ( however there is restriction)
And updates are not allowed through view if there is multiple base relations or grouping operations.